# Using function scoped fixture to setup a class

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures, pytest-fixtures

I have a fixture in `conftest.py` with a function scope.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def registration_setup(
    test_data, # fixture 1
    credentials, # fixture 2
    deployment # fixture 3
    deployment_object # fixture 4
):
    # pre-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()
    yield
    # post-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()
```

I use it in a test class like this:

```
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _inventory_cleanup(self, registration_setup):
        log('Cleanup Done!')
    
    def test_1():
        ...

    def test_2():
        ...
    
    def test_3():
        ...
```

Now I want to create a new test class where I run the `registartion_setup` fixture once for the entire class. The desired behaviour here is, First the pre-test cleanup executes and then all the tests in the new test class execute, followed by the post-test cleanup.
How can I achieve this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @Marco.S for his answer. Just a small additional check to get it to work

```
def reg_setup(request):
    if 'TestClassWhereFixtureShouldRunOnlyOnce' in request.node.nodeid:
        if not request.config.first_test_executed:
            # pre-test cleanup
            do_cleanup()
            request.config.first_test_executed = True
        yield
        if 'test_last' in request.node.nodeid: # Check for the last test case.
            # post-test cleanup
            do_cleanup()
    else:
        # pre-test cleanup
        do_cleanup()
        yield
        # post-test cleanup
        do_cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

You can use the same approach you did on your other test class, but set the fixture scope to `class`:

```py
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def _inventory_cleanup(self, registration_setup):
        log('Cleanup Done!')
    
    def test_1():
        ...

    def test_2():
        ...
    
    def test_3():
        ...
```

But you will then need to change the scope of the fixture `registration_setup` to `class` to avoid a `ScopeMismatch` error.

### Option 2

To keep using it with a `function` scope, I suggest having two fixtures with the same behavior, but with different scopes, like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def registration_setup_for_function(
    test_data, # fixture 1
    credentials, # fixture 2
    deployment # fixture 3
    deployment_object # fixture 4
):
    # pre-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()
    yield
    # post-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()


@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def registration_setup_for_class(
    test_data, # fixture 1
    credentials, # fixture 2
    deployment # fixture 3
    deployment_object # fixture 4
):
    # pre-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()
    yield
    # post-test cleanup
    do_cleanup()
```

If your other fixtures 1, 2, 3 and 4 have `function` scope, you will have to change them also.

### Option 3

If you don't want to have two identical fixtures with different scopes, you can do something like this:

In a `conftest.py` file in the project root:

```py
def pytest_configure(config):
    config.first_test_executed = False
```

Then, wherever you have your fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def registration_setup(
    test_data, # fixture 1
    credentials, # fixture 2
    deployment, # fixture 3
    deployment_object, # fixture 4
    request # Note the request fixture here
):
    if 'TestClassWhereFixtureShouldRunOnlyOnce' in request.node.nodeid:
        if not request.config.first_test_executed:
            # pre-test cleanup
            do_cleanup()
            yield
            # post-test cleanup
            do_cleanup()
            request.config.first_test_executed = True
    else:
        # pre-test cleanup
        do_cleanup()
        yield
        # post-test cleanup
        do_cleanup()
```

I know it is still a bit repeated, but this way your tests inside the class will call the `registration_setup` fixture only once for the whole class, while other tests will call it always. Maybe you will find a better way knowing this now.

More info on the documentation:

[Fixtures can introspect the requesting test context](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-introspect-the-requesting-test-context)

[A session-fixture which can look at all collected tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/special.html#a-session-fixture-which-can-look-at-all-collected-tests)

[pytest_configure(config)](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure)

Comment: This will result in ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the function scoped fixture resgistration_setup with a class scoped request object.

Comment: I've updated the answer considering that.

Comment: The intention of the question was to avoid creating the same fixture with different scope, but thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok. Another option with this new requirement.

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got this while trying out this scenario `ValueError: registration_setup did not yield a value`.

Comment: I think my sample code confused you. I have changed the test class name to clarify it. Please check it again and see if it was because of that.

Comment: No, it wasn't because of that.

Comment: I tried a few things and I think I found the issue, so when I ran this I noticed that post cleanup happens for the first test case and then in the next test since it doesn't pass the `if not request.config.first_test_executed` check and ends up not yielding anything.

Comment: Here is a workaround I found. So you have another check that checks if the test case is the last one and then you move the yield out of the inner `if`. Posted it as an answer for more clarity.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I didn't test my suggestion with `yield`, that's why it worked for me...